# How can I go through every value in a tree?

Tags: java, tree

I have a function in a tree class :

```
class Tree {
Node root;
int countDivisibleBy(int divisor) {
    
}
```

}

How can i search through the tree and divide every value with the given divisor and in the end return the amount of numbers which can be divided by the divisor?

Node looks like this:

```
class Node {
int value;
Node left; 
Node right;

Node (int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Check out this wiki article on [Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive approach:

```
int countDivisibleByRecursive(Node root, int divisor) {
    int returnVal = 0;
    // check for divisibility here
    // ...
    returnVal += isDivisible ? 1 : 0;
    if(root.left != null){
        returnVal += countDivisibleByRecursive(root.left, divisor);
    }
    if(root.right != null){
        returnVal += countDivisibleByRecursive(root.right, divisor);
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

The code can certainly be optimized. E. g. the variable doesn't need to exist, but it's easier to understand the code if it does.

Comment: I am not allowed to edit any of the given things. I cannot add the parameter Node node.

Comment: I didn't mean to change the signature of `countDivisibleBy(int divisor)`. Instead your method `countDivisibleBy(int divisor)` should just be: `return countDivisibleByRecursive(root, divisor)`.

Comment: What is the variable isDivisible ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution for your needs.
In this site link:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/amp/
Is described how to traverse a binary tree. From you code (left node, right node) I got that is s binary.

In this link there are example in java and others languages as well.
Try it.

Comment: I know the traversing algorithm but the thing is in my task i can just give the int parameter and I can't combine the traversing with the dividing